# pip freeze in virtualenv created with and without site packages

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Creating a `virtualenv` **with** site packages:

```
$ virtualenv env
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Activating it ...

```
$ source env/bin/activate
(env)/home/pkara/Workspace
```

Checking number or packages:

```
$ pip freeze | wc -l
0
```

deactivating / removing previous `virtualenv`

```
(env)/home/pkara/Workspace
$ deactivate 
/home/pkara/Workspace
$ rm -rf env/
```

Now creating a `virtualenv` **without** site packages:

```
$ virtualenv env --no-site-packages
New python executable in env/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Activating and counting:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
(env)/home/pkara/Workspace


$ pip freeze | wc -l
0
(env)/home/pkara/Workspace
```

Why in both cases the number of packets is zero?

The number of packages in my system (outside any virtualenv whatsoever):

```
$ pip freeze | wc -l
106
```

Comment: why you want `pip freeze` outputs packages if you didn't install any?

Comment: `pip freeze` shouldn't output the system-wide packages when creating the virtualenv without the option `--no-site-packages` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`virtualenv` has `--no-site-packages` option turned on by default, with or without this option makes no difference:

> --no-site-packages DEPRECATED. Retained only for backward compatibility. Not having access to global site-packages is now the
>   default behavior.

see more on [its doc](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-no-site-packages).

you could re-try with `--system-site-packages` option.